# C# How to get JSON multiple level nested of multiple same name values

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I'm trying to pull out some JSON data values from a JSON response.
I get an array of JSON data and have gotten the parse to JArray to work and get the values of the JProperties that are not nested.
I can't figure out how to get the "id" data out of a property that has nested info in it for categories, components, and capabilities. The "id" data count is not the same for each of the items.

```
"items": [
{
  "deviceId": "DeviceNumber", <-Can get these values OK
  "name": "DeviceName",
  "label": "DeviceLabel",
  "locationId": "LocationId",
  "components": [
    {
      "id": "main", <-NEED THIS
      "label": "DeviceLabel",
      "capabilities": [
        {
          "id": "ID1", <-NEED THIS
          "version": 1 <-NEED THIS
        },
        {
          "id": "ID2", <-NEED THIS
          "version": 1 <-NEED THIS
        },
        {
          "id": "ID3", <-NEED THIS
          "version": 1 <-NEED THIS
        }
      ],
      "categories": [
        {
          "name": "CategoryName", <-NEED THIS
          "categoryType": "manufacturer"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "dth": {
    "deviceTypeId": "deviceID"
  },
  "type": "typeID"
},
...Next item with same info
```

Here is the code I have to get the "deviceId" and the other items that are next to it before components.

```
        JObject parsed = JObject.Parse(deviceListJSONstring);
        JArray array = (JArray)parsed["items"];
        foreach (JObject item in array.Children<JObject>())
        {
            foreach (JProperty property in item.Properties())
            {

                if (property.Name.Equals("deviceId"))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(property.Value);
                    deviceID = property.Value.ToString();
                }
                else if (property.Name.Equals("components"))
                {
                #What needs to be here?
                }
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: Copy and paste your JSON in to https://json2csharp.com/ then deserialize to that model.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to get the data with ["SelectToken with JSONPath"](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SelectToken.htm)

```
var componentsIDs = item.SelectToken("$.components[*]");
var capabilitiesIds = item.SelectTokens("$...capabilities[*]");
var categoriesIds = item.SelectTokens("$...categories[*]");
```